# PowerShell : Changing the value of an object in an array

Tags: powershell

I often consult this site but today is a big day as I am asking my first question!

I regularly code in PowerShell but I'm stuck on one point. To explain it to you I will take an example.

Let's imagine that I create a table in which I enter the result of 2 Get-ADComputer:

```
$tab = @()
$tab += Get-ADComputer PORT-CAEN-15 | Select-Object Name, Test
$tab += Get-ADComputer PORT-CAEN-24 | Select-Object Name, Test
```

The result of the table is the following :

```
Name         Test
----         ----
PORT-CAEN-15 {}  
PORT-CAEN-24 {}
```

How can I modify the "Test" property for each computer ?

Thank you for your answer and don't hesitate to tell me if I'm not using the right terms.

Answer (score 3):

Use a loop. The easiest will be one of the `foreach` variants:

> **Warning:** While you can change *properties* and run *methods* on items in a `foreach` or `ForEach-Object` loop, avoid reassigning the item to a new value. In other .NET languages like C#, assigning a new value like `$_ = 'new string'` will throw an exception. With PowerShell, no exception occurs but the new value will not persist outside of that loop iteration.
>
> This warning still applies to concurrent (thread-safe) collections. These are special collection types in the `System.Collections.Concurrent` namespace which normally are not subject to this limitation, but the same behavior occurs in PowerShell and new values are not retained when the next iteration begins. I recommend a `for` loop in such a scenario where you would modify the collection itself.

```
# We can pipe the computer names to Get-ADComputer instead of concatenating arrays
$computers =
  'PORT-CAEN-15',
  'PORT-CAEN-24' | Get-ADComputer

# foreach is concise and fast, but can't send results down the pipeline by default
foreach( $computer in $computers ) {
  $computer.Test = 'Whatever should go here, can be an object, string, etc.'
}

# More flexible than the foreach keyword, but this is the slowest variant. You can
# send the output down the pipeline though, which can be a huge boon
$computers | Foreach-Object {
  $_.Test = 'Same concept, different loop. $_ and $PSItem reference the current element'
}

# Faster than ForEach-Object and allows you do pass data down the
# pipeline without using special tricks
$computers.ForEach({
  $_.Test = '$_ and $PSItem have the same meaning here as well.'
})
```

- `foreach` is a keyword and lets you loop over each element in the array, giving each iteration the variable name you choose.

  - You cannot pipe data into a `foreach` loop, but due to its nature you really wouldn't *need* to.
  - A downside of this is that ***you also cannot send results further down the pipeline***, but you can wrap the loop with the sub-expression operator `$()` to make it work anyway (this trick does ***not*** work if you use the group-expression operator `()`):

    ```
    $(foreach( $var in 1..10 ) {
      "Value is $_"
    }) | Write-Warning # Simple pipeline demonstration showing it works
    ```
  - You can also wrap `foreach` in a `ScriptBlock` if you want to stream the data and not wait for the loop to finish for the output to return, and execute with the call operator
    `& {LOOP HERE}`. However, you might run into some issues with referencing your defined variables (`ScriptBlocks` have their own scope), so make sure you understand how `ScriptBlocks` work before using this trick.
- `ForEach-Object` is a cmdlet and also lets you loop over every item in an array.

  - This is the slowest variant, but this is also the only one that (in **PowerShell 7+**) grants a
    `-Parallel` flag in order to iterate over your loop *in-parallel*, which can increase processing performance. Unfortunately, there is not an equivalent parameter for earlier versions.
  - When `foreach` is piped *to* (e.g. `1, 2, 3 | foreach { }`), it is processed as an *alias* to `ForEach-Object`. ***This is a weird design decision and can be confusing so watch out for it***.
  - ***Do not provide an array directly as an argument to `-InputObject`***. Pipe the collection to `ForEach-Object` instead. This is because `ForEach-Object` doesn't actually loop over the collection itself, the pipeline will *unroll* the collection and run `ForEach-Object` once for every item in the collection. If you take the pipeline out of the mix, `ForEach-Object` will "iterate" once for the array object you passed in, and will not execute for *each* element inside of the array.

    You can see this in action like so:

    ```
    # Define array
    $array = 1, 2, 3, "four", 5

    # Correct. Loops once for each element in the array
    $array | ForEach-Object { "Value is $_" }

    # Incorrect. The array is not iterated over,
    # only the array object itself is processed
    ForEach-Object -InputObject $array { "Value is $_" }
    ```
- `Array.ForEach` is an intrinsic method that is added to all PowerShell objects. It is both fast to execute and allows you to pass the returned data down the pipeline.

  - There is no equivalent of `-Parallel` for this so parallel execution would need to be implemented by you. IMO this is far from a dealbreaker.
  - This looks very similar to the `Array.ForEach<T>(T[], Action)` [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.foreach?view=net-5.0), except there are additional overloads and none of are generic. [See this page for more information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Arrays?view=powershell-7.1#foreach) about the `Array.ForEach` and `Array.Where` intrinsic methods.

    - Interestingly, unlike other intrinsic members neither `.Array` or `.ForEach` show up as members when an object is piped to `Get-Member -Force`, which is supposed to show intrinsic members and compiler-generated members.

Comment: Another thing worth mentioning is that if you want to _stream_ output from a language statements such as `foreach` to the pipeline (rather than collect all outputs first), use `& { ... }` instead of `$(...)`

Comment: Tobias Weltner has a good write-up on loop performance [here](https://powershell.one/tricks/performance/pipeline). although I don't think he discusses `.foreach()` or `.where()`. There are some interesting caveats discussed. In particular, if you have ScriptBlock logging enabled.

Comment: Really, the only bits in regards to performance I had were a code comment claiming `.Foreach` was the fastest, and I included an additional bullet point about avoiding confusion with the `Array.Foreach` method.

Comment: I've cleaned up my comments too; parting thought: https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/11798 asks for the intrinsic members to be shown by `Get-Member` too, at least on an opt-in basis (the term "intrinsic member" hadn't officially been coined then).

Comment: OK, final final thought: The linked Tobias Weltner article is indeed a great read, and it's unfortunate that its findings haven't yet led to optimizing the slow `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object` cmdlets; the relevant feature request is [GitHub issue #10982](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/10982).  /cc @Steven.

Comment: Optimizing those might be difficult without a code change to PowerShell itself. Based on my understanding slow perf is due to how the pipeline works. It's not the most performant, and is one of the reasons PowerShell isn't considered one of the fastest scripting languages. However, I would argue that PowerShell isn't a great runtime because it's fast (it's not), but rather it often *greatly* reduces the boilerplate code necessary to complete certain operations when compared to other languages. It's definitely a tradeoff but also is why I prefer it for general automation over other languages.

Comment: @mklement0 as always, great references! Bender, I completely agree.  I don't typically encounter performance concerns or resource constraints.  However, when they occur, PoSh still has a lot in the tool box.  Such cases are usually large data sets such that repetition (ie looped code) accumulates otherwise small delays.  Nevertheless, a little technique usually returns satisfactory results.

Comment: All good points in general, but It isn't the _pipeline_ that causes the slowdown, it's the inefficient implementation techniques _inside_ `ForEach-Object` and `Where-Object`. In fact, the pipeline-based workaround  mentioned in the article is only somewhat slower than a `foreach` statement and even outperforms `.ForEach()`: Compare `$array | . { process { "$_!" } }` to `$array | ForEach-Object { "$_!" }` and `$array.ForEach({ "$_!" })`. In short: improving the performance of these - very frequently used - cmdlets would provide a great speed boost to lots of pipeline-based code /cc @Steven.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of ways to do that. A straightforward approach would be to simply loop the results afterward:

```
$tab = @()
$tab += Get-ADComputer PORT-CAEN-15 | Select-Object Name, Test
$tab += Get-ADComputer PORT-CAEN-24 | Select-Object Name, Test

ForEach($Computer in $tab) 
{
    $Computer.Test = "New Value..."
}

$tab
```

Results should be:

```
Name     Test
----     ----
PYEXADM1 New Value...
PXEXADM1 New Value...
```

However, there really isn't an immediate need to use a post-loop. Consider that Test is not normal property returned by `Get-ADComputer`, what you're really doing is returning `[PSCustomObject]`'s inheriting the Name property from the AD computer object, but adding the custom property "Test".  So instead of looping after the fact, we can simply expand that into a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties?view=powershell-7.1).

```
'PORT-CAEN-15', 'PORT-CAEN-24' |
Get-ADComputer |
Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'Test'; Expression = { $_.DNSHostName }}
```

This example does away with the use of the `+=` operator. That's generally a best practice because it's a lot slower than letting PowerShell accumulate the results for you.  After that a hash table is provided that defines the name of the new property and an expression whose return value will be the value of the new property.

Note: The expression can be anything, it doesn't even have to relate back to the object that was passed into `Select-Object`, I used `$_.DNSHostName` just to demonstrate how to reference back to the piped object.

Moreover, and to cite the piping concerns from [Bender the Greatest's nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69164873/4749264), you can continue piping after the `Select-Object` see below scaffolding:

```
'PORT-CAEN-15', 'PORT-CAEN-24' |
Get-ADComputer |
Select-Object Name, @{Name = 'Test'; Expression = { $_.DNSHostName }} |
ForEach-Object {
    # Some other commands...
}
```

Note: `ForEach-Object` is just an example above. anything that will take those objects as input can be put there...

Answer (score 1):

Using `Select-Object` you can add so-called [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) to the object:

```
Select-Object Name, 
              @{Name = 'Test'; Expression = {'Whatever you want here'}}
```

Comment: While this works, I'm not sure it's the best approach if you want to actually modify the object's value. `Select-Object` is really more used for selecting and curating the data view, and if you use this method elsewhere you might unintentionally use an incomplete object or get a type mismatch when working with something expecting the original type. I can't think of a use case where you would want to use `Select-Object` with only specific properties (`*` excepted) unless you are getting ready to export a data structure for use elsewhere.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest I think it always depends.  It's likely those values are going to get set once.  We don't have a robust enough code sample to know.  In my experience deriving custom objects through `Select-Object` rarely causes a problem. If we look at a resulting object like `$Object.PSObject.TypeNames` we can see the object's origins are remembered.  Moreover and typically, if they are passed to another cmdlet or function, so long as they have the correct properties to bind to the correct parameters, it should be fine.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest It's an extension of the OP's own code. It is very common to select only properties you are interested in from an object and this shows how you can select both properties already present and combine with custom properties at the same time.

Comment: I wasn't trying to invalidate your approach, was just giving some cases where it might not be desirable. But, if I return an object without the intent of displaying properties visually or wanting to export a curated view of it, what is the point of selecting only specific properties? It's not like any thrown away (unselected) values will be GC'd while your current script is running (unless you performed said processing in another thread)